# Replicate user permissions for Google Sites/Docs

Tags: google-workspace, google-classic-sites, permissions, user-accounts

I have **User B** temporarily filling the role of **User A**.

User A is owner or editor over several **Sites/Pages** and **Docs**.
The Sites have hundreds of Docs on them.

I want to **replicate** all the Google Sites/Docs permissions from User A to User B.

I have done the Googling, and I have come up with the usual conclusion of just renaming User A to User B, but I would rather not do that so I can still have User A's account active with an Out of office response as User A is on leave.

I have had a look into Google Apps Manager, and may have missed it, but I cannot find any command to do what I need.

Has anyone found a good option?

Comment: I have found a good free Audit tool which lets me easily find out exactly what permissions are set for docs, Sites and other components. 
General Audit Tool for Google Apps
http://www.google.com/enterprise/marketplace/viewListing?productListingId=2463+6187264932609416511&category=&query=GAT

I am still stuck on copying the permissions to a new user.
I could use the Document transfer tool in Google Control Panel but this may cause problems down the line when User A Returns.

Comment: Turns out, free is too good to me true. The General Audit Tool is now no longer free :(

Answer (score 1):

Backupify has a free tool ([Migrator for Google Apps](https://www.backupify.com/free-tools/migrator-google-apps)) that can transfer the complete contents of Google Drive (among other services) to another user.

The key feature here is:

> Access Control Lists, Labels and MIME metadata are all transferred intact with Migrator, so you never need to worry about manually updating sharing lists, permissions or tags for your migrated data.

This means that you can easily move your documents over to user B and move them back to user A later. I've had problems with the Google CPanel document transfer tool, so I would trust Backupify's tool more. Also note that this tool does not work on Sites, but you implied that you have more Docs than Sites.